# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar información de personajes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola estoy tratando de crear un selector de personajes donde al seleccionar una imagen muestra la información de un personaje en específico, luego al seleccionar otra imagen la anterior se oculta y muestra la información del otro personaje tienen alguna idea de cómo hacer esto?

```
<div class="chara-select">
    <img src="chara-1.png" alt="" class="">
    <img src="chara-2.png" alt="" class="">
    <img src="chara-3.png" alt="" class="">

</div>
<br>
<br>
<section id="chara-cont" >

    <div class="container" data-chara="chara-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <h1> chara-1 </h1><br>
                  <!-- info aqui -->
             </div>
            <div class="col-4"><!-- Sprite(dieño del personaje) aqui --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-chara="chara-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <h1> chara-2 </h1><br>
                  <!-- info aqui -->
             </div>
            <div class="col-4"><!-- Sprite(dieño del personaje) aqui --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-chara="chara-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <h1> chara-3 </h1><br>
                  <!-- info aqui -->
             </div>
            <div class="col-4"><!-- Sprite(dieño del personaje) aqui --></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, por favor considera editar y mostrar tu avance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con los efectos `hide` y `show` de `jQuery` puedes lograrlo.

Además puedes controlar la velocidad en que se muestra y oculta el texto agregando los parámetros "slow", "fast", o la duración que desees expresada en milisegundos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#chara2").click(function(){
    $("#p2").show(500);//(500) controla la velocidad en que aparece o desaparece el texto en milisegundos
    $("#p1").hide('slow');
  });
  $("#chara1").click(function(){
    $("#p1").show('fast');
    $("#p2").hide(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <img id="chara1" src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <p id="p1" hidden>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis urna neque, cursus id metus in, ultricies tincidunt mi. Curabitur non vehicula urna. Curabitur metus sapien, fringilla at magna at, ultrices vehicula augue. Mauris vitae urna sodales arcu laoreet consectetur. Donec massa mi, condimentum vel rutrum non, tincidunt sagittis nisi.</p>
  <br>

  <img id="chara2" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
  <p id="p2" hidden>Quisque mattis mattis mi, id semper ex rutrum eu. Nam metus lacus, euismod id sem non, tempor bibendum purus. In hendrerit luctus sem eget porttitor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras nec sapien sem. Vivamus elementum ipsum nibh. Sed dictum feugiat orci, eu luctus orci lacinia ut.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pero no seria muy tedioso el añadir las id una por una ? lo que quería es que se usara el data para predecir que al pinchar la imagen esta sea igual que la id y muestre el contenido me refiero que hay muchas imágenes que muestran la información del personaje

Comment: ok, eso es a otro nivel. Accedí al vínculo que proporcionaste en el comentario de la otra respuesta y realmente deseas algo mucho más complejo de lo que planteas en tu pregunta. Desde ese punto de vista sería una pregunta demasiado amplia. Por ahora puedo sugerirte que le des un vistazo al código fuente de la pagina, se trata de añadir la información de los personajes en un `array` de `JavaScript` y muestras la info según la posición seleccionada en el atributo `data-id`. Por lo que alcancé a observar, [aquí lo hacen uno a uno](https://www.yanderesimulator.com/characters/). Prueba y comenta!

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo puedes lograr con puro CSS. Solo necesitar usar la propiedad y valor `overflow: hidden;` y una transition de .5s o lo que quieras.

Claro. Tienes que crear los estilos para el estado de hover de tus clases **.container**.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo muy simplificado para que luego tú lo personalices y le agregues tu información.

```
// CSS
 .container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
}

.container:hover{
  content: '';
  height: 200px;
}

// HTML
<div class="container" data-chara="chara-1">
        <div class="row">
                <h1> Prsonaje X </h1>
            <div class="col-8">

                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
             </div>
            <div class="col-4"><!-- Sprite(dieño del personaje) aqui --></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Como notarás le agregué una `<p></p>` en donde se supone que va tu info. Ahí escribes todo lo que se va a quedar escondido hasta que le hagas hover al elemento.

Comment: pero mi meta es algo como esto https://www.yanderesimulator.com/characters/

Comment: Bueno compadre pudiste haber empezado por ahí. Te ayudé con el problema de mostrar y ocultar información al hacer hover porque es lo que pediste. Ahora ese ejemplo es más difícil pero creo que con solo CSS lo puedes lograr. Tal vez algo de JavaScript. Claro, depende también qué tan parecido quieres que salga. Mejor publica otra pregunta con lo que realmente quieres y si puedo te ayudo.